# node.js require() cache - possible to invalidate?

Tags: node.js

From the node.js documentation:

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.

Is there a way to invalidate this cache? i.e. for unit testing, I'd like each test to be working on a fresh object.

Comment: NPM module https://github.com/gajus/require-new

Comment: Another NPM module with a watcher: https://www.npmjs.com/package/updated-require

Comment: It's possible to cache the file contents without using require and eval it for different scopes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376161/is-it-possible-to-re-require-a-file-to-get-different-scope/42377173#42377173

Answer (score 362, accepted):

You can always safely delete an entry in require.cache without a problem, even when there are circular dependencies. Because when you delete, you just delete a reference to the cached module object, not the module object itself, the module object will not be GCed because in case of circular dependencies, there is still a object referencing this module object.

Suppose you have:

*script a.js:*

```
var b=require('./b.js').b;
exports.a='a from a.js';
exports.b=b;
```

and *script b.js:*

```
var a=require('./a.js').a;
exports.b='b from b.js';
exports.a=a;
```

when you do:

```
var a=require('./a.js')
var b=require('./b.js')
```

you will get:

```
> a
{ a: 'a from a.js', b: 'b from b.js' }
> b
{ b: 'b from b.js', a: undefined }
```

now if you edit your b.js:

```
var a=require('./a.js').a;
exports.b='b from b.js. changed value';
exports.a=a;
```

and do:

```
delete require.cache[require.resolve('./b.js')]
b=require('./b.js')
```

you will get:

```
> a
{ a: 'a from a.js', b: 'b from b.js' }
> b
{ b: 'b from b.js. changed value',
  a: 'a from a.js' }
```

===

The above is valid if directly running node.js. However, if using tools that have their own module caching system, such as **jest**, the correct statement would be:

```
jest.resetModules();
```

Comment: could you please explain why `{ ... a: undefined}` when requiring `b.js` for the first time ? I would expect to equal `'a from a.js'`. Thank you

Comment: why is a undefined?

Comment: Late reply, but from what I gather `b[a]` is undefined the first time since there's a circular dependency. `a.js` requires `b.js` which in turn requires `a.js`. `a.js` is not yet fully loaded and `exports.a` is yet to be defined, so `b.js` get's nothing.

Comment: any way to do this if I'm using `require.main.require(path)` as described here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860244/how-to-make-the-require-in-node-js-to-be-always-relative-to-the-root-folder-of-t

Comment: Thank you for adding the last paragraph with 'jest.resetModules();', could be really helpful as most tutorials I came accross used Mocha!

Answer (score 260):

If you always want to reload your module, you could add this function:

```
function requireUncached(module) {
    delete require.cache[require.resolve(module)];
    return require(module);
}
```

and then use `requireUncached('./myModule')` instead of require.

Comment: This is perfect in combination with the `fs.watch` method which listens for file changes.

Comment: what is the risk?

Comment: Same question I have, what is the risk of using this solution and not the accepted answer?

Comment: It's the same really. Depending on how the code is structured, things might crash when you try to initialize it again. Ex. if the module starts a server, and listens to a port. The next time you requireUncached the module, it will fail since that port is already opened, and so on.

Comment: An almost perfectly elegant solution, except for `delete` which can be _quite_ slow.

Comment: for some reason this causes memory to pile up on each call (I'm using on a server that calls on each request), switching back to normal `require` fixes the memory issue completely

Comment: it bemuses me that this function isn't called reacquire(), but that's just me.

Comment: see my version, https://stackoverflow.com/a/67437133/830899 if you want to abort the reload if the updated version has syntax errors (useful on sites like glitch where editor updates files as you type)

Comment: @luff: So what the side effects for the same?

Comment: Why is the module name wrapped by `require.resolve`, and not just `require.cache[module]`?

Answer (score 140):

Yes, you can access the cache via `require.cache[moduleName]` where `moduleName` is the name of the module you wish to access. Deleting an entry by calling `delete require.cache[moduleName]` will cause `require` to load the actual file.

This is how you would remove all cached files associated with the module:

```
/**
 * Removes a module from the cache
 */
function purgeCache(moduleName) {
    // Traverse the cache looking for the files
    // loaded by the specified module name
    searchCache(moduleName, function (mod) {
        delete require.cache[mod.id];
    });

    // Remove cached paths to the module.
    // Thanks to @bentael for pointing this out.
    Object.keys(module.constructor._pathCache).forEach(function(cacheKey) {
        if (cacheKey.indexOf(moduleName)>0) {
            delete module.constructor._pathCache[cacheKey];
        }
    });
};

/**
 * Traverses the cache to search for all the cached
 * files of the specified module name
 */
function searchCache(moduleName, callback) {
    // Resolve the module identified by the specified name
    var mod = require.resolve(moduleName);

    // Check if the module has been resolved and found within
    // the cache
    if (mod && ((mod = require.cache[mod]) !== undefined)) {
        // Recursively go over the results
        (function traverse(mod) {
            // Go over each of the module's children and
            // traverse them
            mod.children.forEach(function (child) {
                traverse(child);
            });

            // Call the specified callback providing the
            // found cached module
            callback(mod);
        }(mod));
    }
};
```

Usage would be:

```
// Load the package
var mypackage = require('./mypackage');

// Purge the package from cache
purgeCache('./mypackage');
```

Since this code uses the same resolver `require` does, just specify whatever you would for require.

---

> "Unix was not designed to stop its users from doing stupid things, as
>   that would also stop them from doing clever things." – Doug Gwyn

I think that there *should* have been a way for performing an explicit uncached module loading.

Comment: +1 just for Doug's quote. I needed someone to phrase out what I also believed in :)

Comment: Excellent answer! If you would like to start a node repl with reloading enabled check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/gleitz/6896099).

Comment: awesome. I would add this to the `require.uncache` function.
```
        // see https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8266

        Object.keys(module.constructor._pathCache).forEach(function(k) {
            if (k.indexOf(moduleName)>0) delete module.constructor._pathCache[k];
        }); 
```
Say you've required a module, then uninstalled it, then reinstalled the same module but used a different version that has a different main script in its package.json, the next require will fail because that main script does not exists because it's cached in `Module._pathCache`

Comment: crap. my comment is terrible. I couldn't neatly add code in this comment and it's too late to edit, so I answered. @Ben Barkay if you could edit your question to add the little snippet of code to your `require.uncache`

Comment: Thanks @bentael, I've added this to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @bentael for your investigation, but it seems unfortunately not enough. The main script name is kept in cache in the `packageMainCache` property, which is not accessible from outside.

If I try to update a package with a dependency where the main file has moved, I now get a `Cannot find module` error. I will comment on yout GitHub issue.

Comment: On the `Object.keys` line, why not use `for..of` ?

Answer (score 47):

### There's a *Simple Module for that* (*with tests*)

We had this exact issue while *testing* our code (*delete cached modules so they can be re-required in a fresh state*) so we reviewed all the *suggestions* of people on the various StackOverflow Questions & Answers and put together a *simple* ***node.js module*** (***with tests***):

> [https://www.npmjs.com/package/**decache**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decache)

As you would expect, works for *both* published npm packages and *locally* defined modules. Windows, Mac, Linux, etc.

[image: Build Status]
[image: codecov.io]
[image: Code Climate maintainability]
[image: Dependencies Status]
[image: devDependencies Status]

### How? (*usage*)

Usage is pretty simple:

#### install

Install the module from npm:

`npm install decache --save-dev`

#### Use it in your code:

```
// require the decache module:
const decache = require('decache');

// require a module that you wrote"
let mymod = require('./mymodule.js');

// use your module the way you need to:
console.log(mymod.count()); // 0   (the initial state for our counter is zero)
console.log(mymod.incrementRunCount()); // 1

// delete the cached module:
decache('./mymodule.js');

//
mymod = require('./mymodule.js'); // fresh start
console.log(mymod.count()); // 0   (back to initial state ... zero)
```

If you have any questions or need more examples, please create a GitHub issue:
https://github.com/dwyl/decache/issues

Comment: I've been looking at this and it looks really great for me to use when testing so that I can unload and reload a module under specific conditions, but unfortunately I'm at work and my company shies away from GPL licenses. I only want to use it for testing so I am still considering it because it looks so helpful.

Comment: @Matt_JD thanks for your feedback. which licence would you prefer?

Comment: Work prefers non-copyleft. I thnk most things I've used so far are MIT. I've overcome my current problem by doing var path = require.resolve('module'); delete require.cache[path]; require('module'); Or something like that.

Comment: @Matt_JD We've updated the license to MIT. Good luck with your work! :-)

Comment: this worked amazingly!  Starring this repo and upvoting this answer.

Comment: highly recommend, running fine on latest v14.2.0 as of today

Answer (score 31):

For anyone coming across this who is using Jest, because Jest does its own module caching, there's a built-in function for this - just make sure `jest.resetModules` runs eg. after each of your tests:

```
afterEach( function() {
  jest.resetModules();
});
```

Found this after trying to use [decache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decache) like another answer suggested. Thanks to [Anthony Garvan](https://github.com/dwyl/decache/issues/27#issuecomment-275871860).

Function documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#resetmodules-boolean).

Comment: Thank you so much for this note!

Comment: god how long did I experiment before I found this....thank you!

Answer (score 19):

The solutions is to use:

```
delete require.cache[require.resolve(<path of your script>)]
```

---

<sub>Find here some basic explanations for those who, like me, are a bit new in this:</sub>

Suppose you have a dummy `example.js` file in the root of your directory:

```
exports.message = "hi";
exports.say = function () {
  console.log(message);
}
```

Then you `require()` like this:

```
$ node
> require('./example.js')
{ message: 'hi', say: [Function] }
```

If you then add a line like this to `example.js`:

```
exports.message = "hi";
exports.say = function () {
  console.log(message);
}

exports.farewell = "bye!";      // this line is added later on
```

And continue in the console, the module is not updated:

```
> require('./example.js')
{ message: 'hi', say: [Function] }
```

That's when you can use `delete require.cache[require.resolve()]` indicated in [luff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16060619/1983854):

```
> delete require.cache[require.resolve('./example.js')]
true
> require('./example.js')
{ message: 'hi', say: [Function], farewell: 'bye!' }
```

So the cache is cleaned and the `require()` captures the content of the file again, loading all the current values.

Comment: IMHO This is most appropriate answer

Answer (score 5):

[rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) is great for this use case, you get a new instance with each call. Easy dependency injection for node.js unit testing.

rewire adds a special setter and getter to modules so you can modify their behaviour for better unit testing. You may

inject mocks for other modules or globals like process
leak private variables
override variables within the module.
rewire does not load the file and eval the contents to emulate node's require mechanism. In fact it uses node's own require to load the module. Thus your module behaves exactly the same in your test environment as under regular circumstances (except your modifications).

Good news to all caffeine-addicts: rewire works also with Coffee-Script. Note that in this case CoffeeScript needs to be listed in your devDependencies.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can invalidate cache.

The cache is stored in an object called require.cache which you can access directly according to filenames (e.g. - `/projects/app/home/index.js` as opposed to `./home` which you would use in a `require('./home')` statement).

```
delete require.cache['/projects/app/home/index.js'];
```

Our team has found the following module useful.  To invalidate certain groups of modules.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-resource

Answer (score 5):

I am not 100% certain of what you mean by 'invalidate', but you can add the following above the `require` statements to clear the cache:

```
Object.keys(require.cache).forEach(function(key) { delete require.cache[key] })
```

Taken from @Dancrumb's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23686122/1461850)

Answer (score 4):

I'd add to luff's answer one more line and change the parameter name:

```
function requireCached(_module){
    var l = module.children.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        if (module.children[i].id === require.resolve(_module))
        {
            module.children.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    delete require.cache[require.resolve(_module)];
    return require(_module)
}
```

Comment: So this is to make the function work in submodules? Nice! A shorter way to remove the module from module.children array is by using a filter function:  
module.children = module.children.filter(function(child){ 
 return child.id !== require.resolve(_module);
});

Answer (score 4):

`requireUncached` with relative path:

```
const requireUncached = require => module => {
  delete require.cache[require.resolve(module)];
  return require(module);
};

module.exports = requireUncached;
```

invoke requireUncached with relative path:

```
const requireUncached = require('../helpers/require_uncached')(require);
const myModule = requireUncached('./myModule');
```

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't neatly add code in an answer's comment. But I would use @Ben Barkay's answer then  add this to the `require.uncache` function.

```
    // see https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8266
    // use in it in @Ben Barkay's require.uncache function or along with it. whatever
    Object.keys(module.constructor._pathCache).forEach(function(cacheKey) {
        if ( cacheKey.indexOf(moduleName) > -1 ) {
            delete module.constructor._pathCache[ cacheKey ];
        }
    });
```

Say you've required a module, then uninstalled it, then reinstalled the same module but used a different version that has a different main script in its package.json, the next require will fail because that main script does not exists because it's cached in `Module._pathCache`

Answer (score 2):

If you want a module to simply never be cached (sometimes useful for development, but remember to remove it when done!) you can just put `delete require.cache[module.id];` inside the module.

Comment: where do I add this? my js is not loading in the browser with hot reload...

Answer (score 2):

here's my version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16060619/830899), which handles not loading a file if it has (for example) syntax errors

```
function reacquire(module) {
const fullpath  = require.resolve(module);
const backup = require.cache[fullpath];
delete require.cache[fullpath];

 try {
   const newcopy = require(module);
   console.log("reqcquired:",module,typeof newcopy);
   return newcopy;
 } catch (e) {
    console.log("Can't reqcquire",module,":",e.message);
    require.cache[fullpath] = backup;
    return backup;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Following two step procedure is working perfectly for me.**

After changing `Model` file i-e `'mymodule.js'` dynamically, you need to Delete precompiled model in [mongoose model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25604354/1996802) first then reload it using [require-reload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-reload)

```
Example:
        // Delete mongoose model
        delete mongoose.connection.models[thisObject.singular('mymodule')]

        // Reload model
        var reload = require('require-reload')(require);
        var entityModel = reload('./mymodule.js');
```

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#modules_require_cache) says:

> Modules are cached in this object when they are required. **By deleting a key value from this object, the next require will reload the module.** This does not apply to native addons, for which reloading will result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

If it's for unit tests, another good tool to use is [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire). Everytime you proxyquire the module, it will invalidate the module cache and cache a new one. It also allows you to modify the modules required by the file that you are testing.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small module to delete module from the cache after loading. This forces reevaluation of the module next time it is required. See https://github.com/bahmutov/require-and-forget

```
// random.js
module.exports = Math.random()
const forget = require('require-and-forget')
const r1 = forget('./random')
const r2 = forget('./random')
// r1 and r2 will be different
// "random.js" will not be stored in the require.cache
```

PS: you can also put "self-destruct" into the module itself. See https://github.com/bahmutov/unload-me

PSS: more tricks with Node require in my https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/hacking-node-require/