# Is there any JIT pre-caching support in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, v8

I am using a rather large and performance-intensive nodejs program to generate hinting data for CJK fonts (sfdhanautohint), and for some better dependency tracking I had to end up calling the nodejs program tens of thousands of times from a makefile [like this](https://github.com/be5invis/sfdhanautohint/wiki/Walkthrough#more-makefile).

This immediately brought me to the concern that doing such is actually putting a lot of overhead in starting and pre-heating the JIT engine, so I decided to find something like `ngen.exe` for nodejs. It appears that V8 [already has some support for code caching](https://v8project.blogspot.com/2015/07/code-caching.html), but is there anything I can do to use it in NodeJS?

Searching for [`kProduceCodeCache` in NodeJS's GitHub repo](https://github.com/nodejs/node/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=kProduceCodeCache&type=Code) doesn't return any non-bundled-v8 results. Perhaps it's time for a [feature request](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4766)…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this happens automatically. Node 5.7.0+ automatically pre-caches (pre-heats the JIT engine for your source) the first time you run your code (since PR #4845 / January 2016 here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/4845).

It's important to note you can even pre-heat the pre-heat (before your code is ever even run on a machine, you can pre-cache your code and tell Node to load it).

Andres Suarez, a Facebook developer who works on Yarn, Atom and Babel created [v8-compile-cache](https://github.com/zertosh/v8-compile-cache), which is a tiny little module that will JIT your code and require()s, and save your Node cache into your $TMP folder, and then use it if it's found.  Check out the source for how it's done to suit other needs.

You can, if you'd like, have a little check that runs on start, and if the machine architecture is in your set of cache files, just load the cached files instead of letting Node JIT everything.  This can cut your load time in half or more for a real-world large project with tons of requires, and it can do it on the very first run

Good for speeding up containers and getting them under that 500ms "microservice" boot time.

It's important to note:

1. Caches are binaries; they contain machine-executable code. They aren't your original JS code.
2. Node cache binaries are different for each target CPU you intend to run on (IA-32, IA-64, ARM etc). If you want to pre-cache pre-caches for your users, you must make cache targets for each target architecture you want to support.
3. Enjoy a ridiculous speed boost :)