# Nodejs require returns same old file when requiring a second time after the file changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

So inside my nodejs server file I have the line:

```
tools=require("./tools.js");
```

The tools file contains functions and thelike that I change alot, so I figured instead of restarting the server everytime I change something, I could simply add some way for me to re-require the tools.js, and so I did. However now the problem is, when I start the program, change the tools.js and make it re-require it, it requires it again as if it was still in the state it was when it was first required. What?

Edit: I don't want to restart the app upon a file change, since that would be the same as restarting the server, which is what I want to prevent! So I need something that let's me re-require it, ignoring module caching or whatever.

Any ideas what could help me here?

Answer (score 20):

If you don't want to restart the app do this every time you require it.

```
var path = require('path');
var filename = path.resolve('./tools.js');
delete require.cache[filename];
var tools = require('./tools');
```

Comment: Gives me the error path is not defined. What module is it in?

Comment: Found it, it's in the path module. `path=require("path");`

Comment: I would suggest using `require.resolve()` instead of `path.resolve()` as `require` has specific rules for path resolution. If it's a custom module and you already know both would resolve to the same path, as in this case, then I guess it doesn't really matter. But. In general.

Answer (score 6):

This solved it for me:

```
let tools = require("./tools.js"); 
delete require.cache[require.resolve("./tools.js")];
tools = require("./tools.js");
```

Creds to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210542/node-js-require-cache-possible-to-invalidate/11477602#11477602)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you're running into Node's module caching. http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_caching

You might want to look into a proper reloader for Node instead, if that's an option.  See https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at supervisor. Supervisor can restart the application automatically upon file changes and is simple to setup.

`npm install -g supervisor`

`supervisor app.js`

Answer (score 2):

Once node.js require()s a module, any subsequent call to require() fetches it from memory, the actual module file doesn't get loaded again. What you need to do is use a tool like nodemon (https://github.com/remy/nodemon ), which automatically restarts your app when files are changed.