# Not able to run child process in node kafka consumer

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const child = spawn('dir', ['./kafka'], { shell: true });
child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log("child process started");
});
child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error("failed to start child process");
});

child.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Used above code to execute kafka consumer in a separate child process which is located in kafka folder with name consumer.js.

Getting this error

```
failed to start child process
child process exited with code 127
```

Comment: You're running `dir`, not a consumer process. You should `require('consumer')` if you want to use that file

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the syntax? I can import consumer

Comment: Example : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17613170/2308683