# Clearing require cache

Tags: node.js, caching

I am trying to delete a module from cache as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9210542/1420197).

In the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_require_cache) we read:

> ### require.cache
>
> - Object
>
> Modules are cached in this object when they are required. **By deleting a key value from this object, the next require will reload the module.**

So, I created a file named `1.js` that contains a single line:

```
module.exports = 1;
```

Then I require it via `node` shell:

```
ionicabizau@laptop:~/Documents/test$ node
> require("./1")
1
> require.cache
{ '/home/ionicabizau/Documents/test/1.js': 
   { id: '/home/ionicabizau/Documents/test/1.js',
     exports: 1,
     parent: 
      { id: 'repl',
        exports: [Object],
        parent: undefined,
        filename: '/home/ionicabizau/Documents/test/repl',
        loaded: false,
        children: [Object],
        paths: [Object] },
     filename: '/home/ionicabizau/Documents/test/1.js',
     loaded: true,
     children: [],
     paths: 
      [ '/home/ionicabizau/Documents/test/node_modules',
        '/home/ionicabizau/Documents/node_modules',
        '/home/ionicabizau/node_modules',
        '/home/node_modules',
        '/node_modules' ] } }
# edited file to export 2 (module.exports = 2;)
> require.cache = {}
{}
> require.cache
{}
> require("./1") // supposed to return 2
1
```

So, why does `require("./1")` return `1` when my file contains `module.exports = 2` and the cache is cleared?

Doing some debugging I saw that there is a `Module._cache` object that is not cleared when I do `require.cache = {}`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`require.cache` is just an exposed cache object reference, this property is not used directly, so changing it does nothing. You need to iterate over keys and actually `delete` them.

Comment: `Object.keys(require.cache).forEach(function(key) { delete require.cache[key] })`

Comment: There is an NPM package called [clear-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clear-require) that abstracts this logic.

Comment: @Gajus "abstracts this logic"?? omg is ONE LINE for god sake!

Comment: There is quite a bit more to it. https://github.com/sindresorhus/clear-module/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 1):

```js
for (var i in require.cache) { delete require.cache[i] }
```

If you need to filter specific files, `i` could be filtered with specific Regular Expression or rules at your customization.

```js
for (var i in require.cache) { if (i.startsWith('src/cache/') )delete require.cache[i] }
```