# Node.js: how to reload module

Tags: node.js, module, reload

I am new to NodeJS so probably I am doing some mistakes.

I have written a bunch of code in an external file called myapp. I start NodeJS for windows and from the interpreter window I type:

```
var myapp = require('d:/myapp.js');
```

then I can use my functions and variables in the external module.

The problem is that if I update the code in myapp then the interpreter does not re-read the file and it uses the old version.

Now, is this normal in the first place? How to work around this problem?

P.S.: I have spent hours in internet and searched in many forums including this. It was more confusing then anything else.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js require() cache - possible to invalidate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210542/node-js-require-cache-possible-to-invalidate)

Comment: You have your answer in the duplicate

Comment: Oh! and take care, the accepted answer is not correct, I like this one -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/16060619/1430607

Answer (score 32):

There are [some answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210542/node-js-require-cache-possible-to-invalidate) as suggested in the comments.

However they are not REPL friendly, and might even use extra modules.

Here is a one line solution that you can paste in your REPL, inspired by the discussion on the other question:

```
function nocache(module) {require("fs").watchFile(require("path").resolve(module), () => {delete require.cache[require.resolve(module)]})}
```

The function will delete your module from the cache each time the file changes.
To use it, just paste it in the REPL, call `nocache("d:/myapp.js")`, then use `require` normally.

```
> function nocache(module) {require("fs").watchFile(require("path").resolve(module), () => {delete require.cache[require.resolve(module)]})}
> nocache("d:/myapp.js");
> var myapp = require("d:/myapp.js");
......
> myapp = require("d:/myapp.js");
....
```

Comment: After looking for a quick plug n play solution for a while, I think that your solution is by far the best one out there. You could copy and paste this answer into the tons of similar questions and get a bunch of points.

Comment: Where you write "uncache", you should have written "nocache", right?

Comment: @PedroMachado that is correct, updated answer. Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 18):

The other answers (in duplicate and by @mihai) are all correct, but the most direct answer to this specific example, is

```
delete require.cache['d:/myapp.js'];
```

The module is cached in `require.cache` keyed to the **full** filename.  In this particular case, the full filename (*i.e.* `d:/myapp.js`) was used to load, and so the solution to the problem is very straight forward.

In most cases, however, the full filename is not used or even known.  For example, `require('fs')` would be used to load the filesystem module, but the developer is as a loss to the full and proper filename.  As such, `require.resolve('fs')` will return the filename used as key to cache the module.

Comment: I used `delete require.cache[require.resolve('../path/to/file.js')];` -- easier than finding the full file name

Answer (score 7):

I solved this by adding the following above the `require` statements:

```
Object.keys(require.cache).forEach(function(key) { delete require.cache[key] })
```

Taken from @Dancrumb's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23686122/1461850)