# Clearing Node.js' cache when loading non-js files e.g. graphql language defenitions

Tags: node.js, babeljs, graphql

I want to clear Node's cache from my `graphql` defintions but nothing happens until I make a change to the file where the `require('my.graphql')` statement is. I think this question relates to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685930/clearing-require-cache) and I've tried to do:

```
Object.keys(require.cache).forEach(function(key) {
  delete require.cache[key];
});
```

But it doesn't reload the code. There must be some other caching that is going on that I miss.

Since the example would be a little long, I've forked this [repo](https://github.com/reindexio/graphql-relay-mongodb-pagination) and created a [graphql-branch](https://github.com/gforge/graphql-relay-mongodb-pagination/tree/mongoose-w-gql-lang) that you can install and test adapting the `src/schema.graphql` file:

```
git clone git@github.com:gforge/graphql-relay-mongodb-pagination.git
cd graphql-relay-mongodb-pagination
git checkout git checkout mongoose-w-gql-lang 
npm install
```

The `require('my.graphql')` is mediated via [babel-plugin-inline-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-inline-import).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it turns out that the problem is actually [Babel's cache](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babel-register/#environment-variables-babel-disable-cache) and not Node's. Changing the start in package.json:

```
...
"start": "babel-node ./src/index.js",
```

to

```
...
"start": "BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 babel-node ./src/index.js",
```

fixed the issue.

Comment: Why it returns `'BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: R u using Linux? Windows probably requires a different syntax

Comment: I'm using Windows for development and Linux for production.

Comment: You should not use Babel node in production. The solution for windows is most likely to be different

Comment: ok, please guide me, how I run my `server.js` file in linux server, node can't understand `ES6` codes lile `import` or `<RouterContext/>`

Comment: you can see my `server.js` file in this repository: https://github.com/amerllica/simple-react-ssr-with-css-modules

Comment: Sorry, your setup is pretty different from mine. I suggest you create your own question and try to get an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think using `babel-node` for production in some case like mine is necessary and a good approach.

Answer (score 3):

The babel docs suggest

```
BABEL_CACHE_PATH=/foo/my-cache.json babel-node script.js  # default in /tmp/
BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 babel-node script.js
require('babel-register')({ cache: false });
```

- https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babel-register/

But this doesn't work on Windows 7 when debugging in IntelliJ. After much googling I found where it really lives

```
C:\Users\username\.babel.json
%USERPROFILE%\.babel.json  
$USERPROFILE/.babel.json       # cygwin
```

- https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1148

You can add a script to your package.json to do this for you

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "del %USERPROFILE%/.babel.json",
    "clean": "bash -c 'rm -vf $USERPROFILE/.babel.json'"
  }
}
```

If you are using webpack you can dynamically inject a cacheDirectory: parameter into .babelrc file for easier deletion

babel-node throws an error if you add it directly to the file

webpack.config.js

```
const _       = require('lodash');
const JSON5   = require('json5');

const babelrc = _.extend(
    // WARNING:  ./.babel-cache/ may occasionally get corrupted and need "npm run clean"
    // POSITIVE: ./.babel-cache/ provides a ~30% speed increase in recompile times
    { cacheDirectory: !argv.production && './.babel-cache' },
    JSON5.parse(fs.readFileSync('./.babelrc'))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling you may prefer to clear the cache:

```sh
$ rm -rf ./node_modules/.cache
```