# How can I reset class prototype using `requires`

Tags: javascript, node.js

For the sake of an example, here's something contrived:

```
var util = require('util');
var Me = require('./me.js');

console.log(util.inspect(Me.prototype.something.toString())); // #1      

Me.prototype.name = function() {
  console.log('different');
};

console.log(util.inspect(Me.prototype.something.toString())); // #2

// re-init prototype
var Me = require('./me.js');
console.log(util.inspect(Me.prototype.something.toString())); // #3
```

Output:

```
'function () {\n    console.log(\'original\');\n}'
'function () {\n    console.log(\'different\');\n}'
'function () {\n    console.log(\'different\');\n}'
```

Why doesn't the `require` call re-init *Me* class prototype?

Comment: probably helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15666144/1169798

Comment: Also helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376161/is-it-possible-to-re-require-a-file-to-get-different-scope/42377173#42377173

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Nodejs Documentation, [LINK](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching)

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means
>   (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get
>   exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same
>   file.
>
> Multiple calls to require('foo') may not cause the module code to be
>   executed multiple times. This is an important feature. With it,
>   "partially done" objects can be returned, thus allowing transitive
>   dependencies to be loaded even when they would cause cycles.
>
> If you want to have a module execute code multiple times, then export
>   a function, and call that function.

Answer (score 1):

`require` caches the code, so when called repeatidly it doesn't reload it again.  Since the `Me` object is still in memory it doesn't get reloaded when you `require` it again.

If you want to do this you have to delete `Me` from the module cache.

See this answer [How to remove module after "require" in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666144/how-to-remove-module-after-require-in-node-js)