# How to clear/debug local modules cache

Tags: node.js

I'm getting a very annoying bug when it comes to node caching local modules. I have the file `webserver.js` which exports an object.

When I update the code in the file, the changes are not reflected. So I assume node is somehow caching this.

How doe one debug this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666144/how-to-remove-module-after-require-in-node-js ?

Comment: Well, you need to restart the node process, AKA the server for the cache to be cleared. When you work on the node.js backend using `node`, you usually must restart the server between changes. Either manually or through a script like Gulp.js