# Node TypeScript delete require cache

Tags: node.js, typescript

I want to re-require a module in TypeScript and Node multiple times for testing. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666144/how-to-remove-module-after-require-in-node-js) post that should work by using

```
const config = require('./foo');
delete require.cache[require.resolve('./foo')];
```

However, this does not work for me. Also, when I print out the object `require.cache`, it is empty.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem in `jest` tests. What helped me is the [resetModules](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#resetmodules-boolean) call before test cases.

Comment: You, man, are the single most awesome person in this planet at this exact moment in the history of humankind.