# Mocha: Can't stub function in file that was already required in another test file

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, mocha.js, sinon

I'm using Mocha to run a test suite on `fileToTest.js` with requires `greeting.js`

```
// --fileToTest.js--

const { greeting } = require('./greeting');

module.exports = () => greeting();
```

```
// --greeting.js--

module.exports.greeting = () => 'hi!';
```

By itself, this test file successfully stubs `greeting`.

```js
// --test2.js--
let parent;
const sinon = require('sinon');
const chai = require('chai');
const greeting = require('../../greeting.js');

const { expect } = chai;

describe('stubbed /hi', () => {
  before(async () => {
    sinon.stub(greeting, 'greeting').callsFake((req, res, next) => 'bye!');
    parent = require('../../parent.js');
  });

  after(async () => {
    greeting.greeting.restore();
  });
  it('should say bye', async function () {
    expect(parent()).to.be.equal('bye!');
  });
});
```

However if I run a test suite and have another test file that requires `fileToTest.js`, like `test1.js` below, the first test above (`test2.js`) won't stub greeting.

```js
// --test1.js--
const chai = require('chai');
const fileToTest = require('../../fileToTest.js');

const { expect } = chai;

describe('not stubbed /hi', () => {
  it('should say hi', () => {
    expect(fileToTest()).to.be.equal('hi!');
  });
});
```

It seems once `test1.js` requires `fileToTest`, mocha doesn't reload the `fileToTest` on the `test2.js`'s require. So `fileToTest` is stuck with the old greeting function.

Whats the proper way to stub a function in this situation?

[Repo](https://github.com/DashBarkHuss/mocha_stub)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666144/how-to-remove-module-after-require-in-node-js#answer-15666221) worked. I had to delete the cache.

```
  before(async () => {
    delete require.cache[require.resolve('../../fileToTest.js')]; // <------

    sinon.stub(greeting, 'greeting').callsFake((req, res, next) => 'bye!');
    fileToTest = require('../../fileToTest.js');
  });
```