# How to stub function used on a server in mocha test suite

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, server, mocha.js

I'm trying to stub `auth.session` when testing endpoint `/allowUser2` on an express server `app.js`.

```js
//--auth.js--
module.exports.session = (req, res, next) => {
  req.user = null;
  next();
};
```

```js
//--app.js--
const express = require('express');

const auth = require('./auth');

const app = express();
app.use(auth.session);
app.get('/allowUser2', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.user) return res.status(401).send();
  if (req.user.user === 2) return res.status(200).send();
});

app.listen(4001).on('listening', () => {
  console.log(`HTTP server listening on port 4001`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

If I just have this one test file `test1.js` in my test suite, `auth` gets stubbed successfully.

```js
//--test1.js--
let app;
const sinon = require('sinon');
const auth = require('../../auth.js');
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const { expect } = chai;

chai.use(chaiHttp);
let agent;
describe('should allow access', () => {
  before(async () => {
    // delete require.cache[require.resolve('../../app.js')]; // causes Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use
    sinon.stub(auth, 'session').callsFake((req, res, next) => {
      req.user = { user: 1 };
      next();
    });
    app = require('../../app.js');
    agent = chai.request.agent(app);
  });

  after(async () => {
    auth.session.restore();
  });
  it('should not allow access', async function () {
    const response = await agent.get('/allowUser2');
    expect(response.status).to.be.equal(200);
  });
});
```

However, if I have more than one test file that requires `app.js` then I have a problem. If `app.js` was already required in another test file, such as `test2.js` below, node doesn't reload `app.js` when it's required again in `test1.js`. This causes `app.js` to call the old `auth.session` function, not the new stubbed one. So the user isn't authenticated and the test fails.

```js
//--test2.js--
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const app = require('../../app.js');

const { expect } = chai;

chai.use(chaiHttp);
const agent = chai.request.agent(app);
describe('route /allowUser2', () => {
  it("shouldn't allow access", async function () {
    const response = await agent.get('/allowUser2');
    expect(response.status).to.be.equal(401);
  });
});
```

I tried to reload the `app.js` by using `delete require.cache[require.resolve('../../app.js')];`. This worked when reloading a file with a plain [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66809269/mocha-cant-stub-function-in-file-that-was-already-required-in-another-test-fil), but when the file is a server like `app.js` this causes an error: `Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use`.

Recreate:

1. download [Repo](https://github.com/DashBarkHuss/mocha_stub_server/commit/6119b870fb6c5b292dc5407f00942a29beff59ad)
2. `npm i`
3. `npm test`

How do you stub a function on the server?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Proposed Solution https://github.com/DashBarkHuss/mocha_stub_server/pull/1

One problem is the way you are using a direct method reference in app.js prevents Sinon from working. https://gist.github.com/corlaez/12382f97b706c964c24c6e70b45a4991

The other problem (address in use) is because each time we want to get a reference to app, we are trying to create a server in the same port. Breaking that app/server creation into a separate step alleviates that issue.

Comment: this still gave me "Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use"

Comment: oh I see, you have updated your repo branch with changes of your other answers.

Comment: sorry, just updated with to the link to the commit of the non-working one

Answer (score 0):

One solution is turn `app.js` into a function that starts the server on a port number passed in as an argument. Then change the port randomly when requiring. I do not like this option because there may be some reason to keep the app on a specific port.

`app.js`

```js
const express = require('express');

const auth = require('./auth');

module.exports = (port) => {
  const app = express();
  app.use(auth.session);
  app.get('/allowUser2', (req, res) => {
    if (!req.user) return res.status(401).send();
    if (req.user.user === 2) return res.status(200).send();
  });
  app.listen(port).on('listening', () => {
    console.log(`HTTP server listening on port ${port}`);
  });
  return app;
};
```

when requiring

```js
    app = require('../../app.js')((Math.random() * 10000).toString().slice(0, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exporting the `app` in `app.js`, I export a function that launches the server and returns the server instance and app. By exporting the server instance I have the ability to close the server. The app is needed to pass into chai. Make sure `const app = express();` is in this function and not before it or it won't recreate.

```js
const express = require('express');

const auth = require('./auth');

const port = 4000;
module.exports = () => {
  const app = express();
  app.use(auth.session);
  app.get('/allowUser2', (req, res) => {
    if (!req.user) return res.status(401).send();
    if (req.user.user === 2) return res.status(200).send();
  });
  app.post('/allowUser2', (req, res) => {
    if (!req.user) return res.status(401).send();
    if (req.user.user === 2) return res.status(200).send();
  });
  return {
    server: app.listen(port).on('listening', () => {
      console.log(`HTTP server listening on port ${port}`);
    }),
    app,
  };
};
```

Then in my tests I can launch the server in `before` and close the server in `after` in **both** tests.

```js
let app;
const sinon = require('sinon');
const auth = require('../../auth.js');
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const { expect } = chai;

chai.use(chaiHttp);
let server;
describe('route /allowUser2', () => {
  before(async () => {
    // delete require.cache[require.resolve('../../app.js')]; // causes an error: `Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use`.
    sinon.stub(auth, 'session').callsFake((req, res, next) => {
      req.user = { user: 2 };
      next();
    });
    server = require('../../app.js')();
    agent = chai.request.agent(server.app);
  });

  after(async () => {
    server.server.close(() => {
      console.log('Http server closed.');
    });
    auth.session.restore();
  });
  it('should allow access', async function () {
    const response = await agent.get('/allowUser2');
    expect(response.status).to.be.equal(200);
  });
});
```

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const { expect } = chai;

chai.use(chaiHttp);
let server;
let agent;
describe('route /allowUser2', () => {
  before(async () => {
    server = require('../../app.js')();
    agent = chai.request.agent(server.app);
  });

  after(async () => {
    server.server.close(() => {
      console.log('Http server closed.');
    });
  });
  it("shouldn't allow access", async function () {
    const response = await agent.get('/allowUser2');
    expect(response.status).to.be.equal(401);
  });
});
```

working [repo](https://github.com/DashBarkHuss/mocha_stub_server/)