# Export function first and object subsequently

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have a custom module and would like to provide a method to initialize it on first `require`, but directly return an object on subsequent requires.

But the module gets cached when first required and therefore subsequent requires still return the `init` function instead of returning `obj` directly.

**server.js:**

```js
var module = require('./module.js');
var obj = module.init();
console.log('--DEBUG: server.js:', obj); // <-- Works: returns `obj`.

require('./other.js');
```

**other.js:**

```js
var obj = require('./module.js');
console.log('--DEBUG: other.js:', obj); // <-- Problem: still returns `init` function.
```

**module.js:**

```js
var obj = null;

var init = function() {
    obj = { 'foo': 'bar' };
    return obj;
};

module.exports = (obj) ? obj : { init: init };
```

How can I work around that problem? Or is there an established pattern for achieving such?

But I would like to keep `obj` cached, because my real `init` does some work I would rather not do on every `require`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some ways to clear the require cache. You may check here [node.js require() cache - possible to invalidate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210542/node-js-require-cache-possible-to-invalidate)
However, I think that this is not a good idea. I'll suggest to pass the module which you need. I.e. initialize it only once and distribute it to the other modules.

server.js:

```
var module = require('./module.js');
var obj = module.init();

require('./other.js')(obj);
```

other.js:

```
module.exports = function(obj) {
    console.log('--DEBUG: other.js:', obj); // <-- The same obj
}
```

module.js:

```
var obj = null;

var init = function() {
    obj = { 'foo': 'bar' };
    return obj;
};

module.exports = { init: init };
```