# Node.js - What's the scope of the require()d modules?

Tags: node.js, express, requirejs, require

I am trying to organize a Node.js application developed with Express 4 and am confused about the scope of modules which are imported with require().

Imagine that I use `require('./services/user')` to import a service in a module such as **routes/user.js**:

```
var userService = require('./services/user');
```

Then I do the same `require('./services/user')` in another module **routes/department.js**.

My question is: is userService the same instance in user.js and department.js or each of them has it's own userService object? That is to say, once you've exported some element through module.exports = XXX if you require the same file, will you get always the same instance? Could you show me where in the Node.js docs that's specified?

Comment: Are routes/user.js and route/department.js required by the same code?

Comment: Yes, in the express app.js module: app.use('/users', userRoutes);app.use('/departments', departmentRoutes);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have theses files:

```
.
|_. app.js
|_. routes/
  |_. user.js
  |_. department.js
  |_. services/
    |_. user
```

And your code do this:

```
app.js call user.js
    user.js call user
app.js call department.js
    department.js
```

In that case, at the first time user is required, it is put on cache in `require.cache`.

Then the second time it is called, the caller get `require.cache['./service/user']`, where is stored your object.

As such, you do have the same object in both department.js and user.js.

Source:

- http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_caching
- http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_cycles (helped me understand)
- [Understanding Node.js modules: multiple requires return the same object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887318/understanding-node-js-modules-multiple-requires-return-the-same-object)
- [Self modifying code in node.js, would cluster work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289193/self-modifying-code-in-node-js-would-cluster-work) (about require.cache)

EDIT:

Other helpful links:

[node.js require() cache - possible to invalidate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210542/node-js-require-cache-possible-to-invalidate)

Comment: Thanks! Perfect answer. So if I understood well, as long as there's a common ancestor module all imported modules are catched and shared among all of them?

Comment: That s right, as long as it s the same instance of node that is started, the required module are shared among all module.