# How do I clear express.js cache to serve a JSON file that updates every x seconds?

Tags: node.js, json, express, reload

I'm currently writing a program that displays new information in JSON format via express.js that will be used by another program - currently its purpose is to report CPU usage every second. I don't have a problem with the JSON file itself updating, but I can't seem to get express.js to serve the newest version of the file - it seems to cache the first version and then ignore any updates to the file so the oldest entry is always served.

I've tried deleting the require cache, installing express-reload etc. but nothing seems to solve the issue.

This is the loop that collects the data and puts it in a JSON file. It then calls the webserver to serve that file.

```
    setInterval(() => {
        Monitor.run()

        ServerInstance.serveData(require('../data.json'));
    }, 1000);
```

And then this is the `serveData` function:

```
serveData (data) {
        this.app.get('/', (_request, response) => {
            response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            response.json(data);
        })
}
```

EDIT: Tried using fs.readFile(...) to grab the data fresh and then serve it to Express. The console log reports the data updating as it should be, but when the same data is passed through to Express (as you can see below) it's not updating. Am I missing something really obvious?

```
        fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../data.json', 'utf-8', (error, data) => {
            if (error) console.error(error);

            // This reports the right information
            console.log(data);
            // This still displays the first data point since the program started
            ServerInstance.serveData(data);
        })
```

Comment: Note: I've used Postman as well as 2 browsers to make sure the problem wasn't unique to one of those systems.

Comment: `data` is currently populated via a `require` import to the JSON file. You're right, that definitely doesn't work - but that's the problem, I don't know how to do it in a way such that it dynamically refreshes the file on each file update

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NODE.JS caching JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588279/node-js-caching-json)

Comment: I have tried `delete require.cache[require.resolve('../data.json')]` as well as `require.cache = {};` to no avail. Is there something I'm missing here? It just doesn't seem to be clearing the old cache.

Comment: have you tried using fs instead?

Comment: I've added an edit to this post showing the current code. As mentioned the console.log() reports accurate data which changes every second (expected) but when the same data is sent to the function that handles displaying it via Express it still shows the very first data point, not the latest one

Comment: that looks weird. You're adding the route in express repeatedly, i don't know how/if that works.

Comment: This code doesn’t make sense. You’re repeatedly setting the route handler every time you call that function. Create the route handler once. Read the data in the handler if a timer has expired or whatever, otherwise serve the cached data.

Comment: Is there a particular reason the data has to be loaded into express to be served (any transformations)? If not, simply serving the file statically may work better

`app.get("/data.json",(req, res) => res.sendFile("filepathhere"))`

Comment: Yeah, I've essentially just overcomplicated this for myself. The solution above sorted it out in terms of serving it with sendFile (for my use case). Thanks for all the help.