# Gulp, Mocha, Watch Not Reloading My Source Files

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, gulp

I am attempting to get gulp working to help automate some unit testing. I have the following gulp file.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    mocha = require('gulp-mocha');

gulp.task('unit', function() {
    return gulp.src('test/unit/**/*.js')
        .pipe(mocha({ reporter: 'spec' }))
        .on('error', handleError);
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(['src/**/*.js', 'test/unit/**/*.js'], ['unit']);
});

gulp.task('test', ['unit', 'watch']);
```

When I run 'gulp unit', the tests run fine.

When I run 'gulp test', the tests run, and it appears that 'watch' is working. If I make a change to one of the test files, the tests rerun correctly, taking into account the changes I made in the test file.

If I make changes to my source files, the tests also re-run, but they DO NOT run against the updated version of the source file.

My thought is that somehow, the source file is being cached, but I cannot find any others who seem to have had this issue or find a solution.

Thanks for helping this Gulp/Node/Mocha newbie!

Comment: Your setup looks just fine to me. Are you sure your tests are requiring the file which you've edited (and not a copy of it)?

Comment: Yes. The tests are requiring the correct file. Remember, when I run "gulp unit" without "watch" it works great. When I run the tests using the mocha CLI, it also runs fine. It only appears to occur (the source file seemingly being cached) when the tests automatically rerun because "watch" saw a change in my source file.

Comment: I've got the exact same problem (but jasmine, not mocha), any solution?

Comment: I have not yet found a solution. I am currently not using watch. Had to actually get some work done! :-)

Comment: I just tried this and did not have any problems. I set up my `gulp.watch`, everything looks good, and then I deleted the contents of a src file, and those tests fail. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue but i found a fix,

The issue is that require in nodejs is caching your src files when you are running your tests via watch

I used the following function in my test file to invalidate the cache of the src file, in replace of require.

**Apparently doing this can be dangerous, please see the link at the bottom of my post for more information. Development use only ;)**

*Coffeescript - module-test.coffee*

```
nocache = (module) ->
    delete require.cache[require.resolve(module)]
    return require(module)

Module = nocache("../module")
describe "Module Test Suite", () ->
    newModule = new Module();
    ...
```

*Javascript - module-test.js*

```
var Module, nocache;
nocache = function(module) {
    delete require.cache[require.resolve(module)];
    return require(module);
};
Module = nocache("../src/module");

describe("Module Test Suite", function () {
    newModule = new Module();
    ...
```

see here for more information: [node.js require() cache - possible to invalidate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210542/node-js-require-cache-possible-to-invalidate)

Comment: Thanks! I have also been thinking more about this. I have not tested this approach, but it looks valid to me. Also, I thought about invalidating all modules in a before all tests hook somehow. Have not tested that approach either. Either way, your answer will solve the issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to mod all my tests so I just jammed this function right before I start piping test files to mocha:

```
function freshFiles(chunk, enc, cb){
    _.forOwn(require.cache, function(value, key){
        if (key.indexOf('lib') !== -1 && key.indexOf('node_modules')===-1){
            delete require.cache[key];
        }
    });
}
```

This targets my lib folder but nothing in the node_modules path.

In gulp it looks like:

```
gulp.task('test', function () {
    var mocha = require("gulp-mocha");
    freshFiles();
    gulp.src(testSources)
        .pipe(mocha({ reporter: 'spec', growl: 'true' }))
        .on('error', gutil.log);

});
```