# Get updated file in each request nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Basically, I wrote a server that response a js file(object format) to users who made the request. The js file is generated by two config file. I call them **config1.js** and **config2.js**.

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var _ = require('underscore');

app.use('/config.js', function (req, res) {
    var config1 = require('config1');
    var config2 = require('config2');
    var config = _.extend(config1, config2);
    res.set({'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'});
    res.send(JSON.stringify(config));
});
```

For what I am understanding, every time I make a request to **/config.js**, it will fetch the latest code in config1 and config2 file even after I start server. However, if I start server, make some modification in **config1.js**. then make the request, it will still return me the old code. Can anyone explain and how to fix that? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concat files and extend objects aren't equal operations. You can read the files via 'fs' module, parse objects, extend, and send.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use require in order to load your files because it is not its purpose, it caches the loaded file (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210542/node-js-require-cache-possible-to-invalidate) for more information), that is why you get the same content every time you make a request.
Use a tool like [concat-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat-files) instead, or concat it "by hand" if you prefer.