# How do I prevent @require from caching external js scripts

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, scriptish

I'm currently trying to figure out how I can include a javascript, I have on my webserver, in my scriptish/greasemonkey script and make it reload the script everytime the userscript gets called.

I'm editing the script on my webserver and I really don't want to reinstall the userscript each time I make changes on the included script.

Is there any way around this problem? I've been searching for an answer but had no luck so far.

So to be clear, my userscript looks like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @id             HET
// @name           SettingsHandler
// @version        1.0
// @namespace      HET
// @require        http://urltoscript/scripts/he/lib.js
// @run-at         document-end
// ==/UserScript==
```

and my external script looks like this:

```
alert('got it');
```

All still very easy for testing purposes. This setup works, but only the first time and when I change my lib.js script, then the userscript still reads the old one. Is there a way to prevent the userscript from caching the external script? Or is there any other metatag that can help me?

Thanks in advance,
Dave

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210542/node-js-require-cache-possible-to-invalidate

Comment: How does this apply to Scriptish or Greasemonkey?

Comment: [`@require` is for caching at install time.](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40require) - "Each @require is downloaded once, when the script is installed, and stored on the user's hard drive alongside the script." If you don't want caching, just insert a `<script>` tag into the page.

Comment: @rampion huh? <script> tag is not valid js code. How can you do that in a user.js file?...

Comment: @RyanLee Rob M’s answer below does exactly what I said.

Comment: Most of the solutions in this answer and even on github discussions have no effect, or, for example, remove breakpoints on refresh. That's additionally to http CORS problem, and additionally to lack of edit and continue on Fox. Unfortunately, most practical solution is to use file:/// and Chrome.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the only workable answer
https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/475

Recommended is option 4. However they are loaded asynchronously so loading orders might differ

> There are several ways to ease your pain. :)
>
> 1. You can increase the version number before saving the script and all
>      external resources will be reloaded.
> 2. After setting "Config mode" to
>      "Advanced" you can configure the external update interval. Note:
>      "Always" still means after the resource was used. So you might need to
>      execute/load the page twice.
> 3. If you use Tampermonkey Beta (Chrome or
>      Firefox) you can edit the external resource in place (because there
>      now is a edit button besides the delete button).
> 4. Copy the resources
>      and store them locally. After you've enabled "Local file access" at
>      Chrome's extension management page or Tampermonkey's settings page (if
>      you're using Firefox) you can @require them via a local file:// URI.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure how to accomplish this with GM/userscript directives, but you could easily add the script yourself and append a timestamp to the url to prevent the browser from caching it:

```
var remoteScript = document.createElement('script');
remoteScript.src = 'http://domain.com/path/to/script.js?ts='+(+new Date());
remoteScript.onload = init;
document.body.appendChild(remoteScript);

function init() {
  ... do stuff
}
```

Comment: That wont work with CSP blocking you from accessing `domain.com`.

Comment: @TomášZato:  The question said the `@require` directive would point to JS code on "[their] web server" so I don't think local files are an issue.

Answer (score 4):

The answer from [Rob M.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30109848/3276634) doesn't work for me, because Tampermonkey script location *and* target site where it got injected could be different. For example, in my case I also have a locally running webserver to develop in an IDE using Tampermonkey for Firefox without requiring any file system access for Tampermonkey from the Browser.

This script should got injected to a third party site like example.com, where it applys modifications. So the browser would block this script, since it's from a different domain than example.com.

During development, I'd like to get my script without any caching to apply changes immediately. Worked around this by fetching the scripts content using `GM.xmlHttpRequest. Additionally, a GET parameter with the current timestamp acts as cache buster:

```
let url = `http://localhost/myscript.js?ts=${(+new Date())}`

GM.xmlHttpRequest({
    method: "GET",
    url: url,
    onload: function(response) {
        let remoteScript = document.createElement('script')
        remoteScript.id = 'tm-dev-script'
        remoteScript.innerHTML = response.responseText
        document.body.appendChild(remoteScript)
    }
})
```

Notice that since `GM.xmlHttpRequest` can bypass the same origin policy, access musst be explicitly granded in the head of your script:

```
// @grant        GM.xmlHttpRequest
```

Comment: This is the only solution here that worked for me (not only because I have it on different domain e.g. localhost or similar), but also because my Firefox 82 forces http:// to https:// . Thank you very much!

Comment: I literally just figured this out, I wish I would have found this answer a couple of days ago. The date is a nice addition though. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is to retrieve my files in a text format via `GM_xmlhttpRequest`, wrap that inside of an `eval()` and then execute functions as though `@require` was used.

It's worth noting that using `eval` is extremely dangerous and should almost [never be used](https://dev.to/amitkhonde/eval-is-evil-why-we-should-not-use-eval-in-javascript-1lbh). That being said, this is the exception for me as there is low risk.

In my case, I have a couple of different scripts that need to be run before my main application script (such as utility functions). Therefore, similar to how you would place `<script>` tags in an order depending on when you want them to run, I order them to run first to last in an `Array`.

Also, I wrap all my TM functions inside of an `initialize()` function, and that's what I call at the end which kicks off my script.

```
(async function() {
    try {
        const scriptsToExecute = [
            { resource: 'waitForElement', url: 'https://www.example.org/waitForElement.js', },
            { resource: 'utils', url: 'https://www.example.org/utils.js', },
            { resource: 'main', url: 'https://www.example.org/mainApp.js'},
        ];

        const getScripts = await retrieveScripts(scriptsToExecute).catch(e => {debugger;console.error('Error caught @ retrieveScripts',e);});
        if (getScripts?.status !== "success" || !Array.isArray(getScripts?.scripts || getScripts?.find(f => f.status !== "success"))) throw {getScripts};

        try {
            const scripts = getScripts?.scripts;
            const mainAppScript = scripts?.find(f => f?.resource === "main");

            const scriptsToExecute = scripts?.filter(f => f?.resource !== "main");
            for (let i in scriptsToExecute){
                if (scriptsToExecute[i]?.status !== "success" || !scripts[i]?.retrieved) throw {"erroredScript": scripts[i]}
                const thisScript = scripts[i]?.retrieved;
                // eslint-disable-next-line
                eval(thisScript?.script);
            }
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            eval(mainAppScript);
            try {
                // once you've eval'd the script, you can call functions inside that script from within your UserScript environment
                // all my main app scripts are wrapped inside of a function called `initialize()`.
                // though once you've eval'd the script, you can call whatever you want.
                initialize();  
            } catch (err){debugger; console.error('Error caught @ attempting to initialize', err);}
        } catch(err){debugger; console.error('Error caught @ top level', err);}

    } catch (err) {debugger}

    async function retrieveScripts(scriptsToRetrieve){
        try {
            const scriptsContent = await Promise.all(scriptsToRetrieve.map(m => retrieveScript(m))).catch(e => {debugger;});
    
            if (!Array.isArray(scriptsContent) || scriptsContent?.length !== scriptsToRetrieve?.length && scriptsContent?.find(f => f.status !== "success")) {debugger;return {status: "error", msg: "unable to retrieve the script(s) requested.", scriptsContent,};}
            else return {status: "success", "scripts": scriptsContent};
        }
        catch (err){debugger;return {status: "error", msg: "(caught) unable to retrieve the script(s) requested.", scriptsToRetrieve, "error": err, "errorStringified": String(err)};}
    
        function retrieveScript(scriptToRetrieve){
            if (!scriptToRetrieve?.url) return {status: "error", msg: "no url found", scriptToRetrieve};
            try {
                    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                        GM_xmlhttpRequest({
                            method: "GET",
                            url: scriptToRetrieve.url,
                            onerror: function (response) {debugger;return reject({status: "error", response, scriptToRetrieve });},
                            onload: function (response) {
                                if (response?.status !== 200) {debugger;return reject({status: "error", response, scriptToRetrieve });}
                                else {
                                    try {
                                        if (response?.response) {
                                            scriptToRetrieve.script = response.response;
                                            return resolve({status: "success", "retrieved": scriptToRetrieve})
                                        }
                                        else throw {status: "error", "response": response.response, scriptToRetrieve }
                                    } catch (err) {return reject(err);}
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
            } catch (err){debugger}
        }
    }

})();
```

Once you've `eval`'d your scripts, you can now run them from within the context of your Userscript. What's more, if you initialize any variables from within the function where you use `eval`, they are available to you as well (such as machine-specific code). Or if you have `eval`'d scripts before this, all those functions will available as well -- essentially importing them.

Comment: The best workaround ever! I made class methods out of these functions and created an instance from the class on TM start. Everything works like a charm. The Loader class doesn't have to be edited often, so caching is OK for it, while other scripts are loaded directly from the server. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can add the following to your .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "filename.js">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "0"
</FilesMatch>
```

And remove it when you are done developing.

Comment: do you even know what tampermonkey is?

Comment: Sure, although I didn't think that was particularly relevant to the question.

Comment: This answer is correct.  The question said their @require directive would point to JS code on "[their] web server".  If that server runs Apache, then this .htaccess code should solve the problem just fine.

Comment: not specific to tampermonkey. does not solve the issue when using require with tampermonkey. for example, my require is calling a raw file from GitHib where I manage my script. Tampermonkey is not updating it, so a solution is needed to stop tampermonkey caching scripts and to call the fresh one each time.