# require a new instance of Node module

Tags: node.js, node-modules

A new instance of third-party module should be required in one of the modules.

```
// a
...
exports.thirdParty = require('third-party');
```

---

```
// b
...
exports.thirdParty = require('third-party');
```

---

```
// first-party
...
exports.thirdParty = requireFreshInstance('third-party');
```

---

```
// app.js
var assert = require('assert');
var a = require('a');
var firstParty = require('first-party');
var b = require('b');

assert(a.thirdParty === b.thirdParty);
assert(firstParty.thirdParty !== a.thirdParty);
assert(firstParty.thirdParty !== b.thirdParty);
```

All of the listed modules have similar package requirements,

```
dependencies: {
  "third-party": "^1"
}
```

And the requirement is that it should stay intact, no tricks like `"third-party": "git://..."` are allowed.

Let's say the user controls only `first-party` module and can't modify `third-party` module to have a new `factory` method that would return a new instance.

I'm aware of the fact  that `third-party` is cached once if the version is the same in all cases (technically it is full path to `third-party` that matters), most likely `.thirdParty` properties in all objects are equal.

How can this problem be solved in Node.js programmatically (not with package.json)?

Comment: maybe related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210542/node-js-require-cache-possible-to-invalidate. Try using `delete require.cache['third-party']`.

Comment: Maybe this module `https://github.com/gajus/require-new` could solve your issue?

Comment: @zangw Great, thanks, looks like exactly what I need. Feel free to post it as an answer if you wish.

Comment: @peacer212 Yes, it is related but the problem is more complex. deleting module cache will affect all modules that require 'third-party'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one module [`require-new`](https://github.com/gajus/require-new) could meet your requirement.

- `require-new` requires a new module object.
- `require-new` does not affect the state or behavior of require
  method.
- `require-new` has been designed to be used for module testing.

Here are sample from this module.

```
require('./rand.js'); // 0.697190385311842
require('./rand.js'); // 0.697190385311842
```

Modules are cached in a `require.cache` object when they are required.

`require-new` deletes the key value from the `require.cache` object associated with the module you are requesting, making the module reload:

```
requireNew('./rand.js'); // 0.2123227424453944
requireNew('./rand.js'); // 0.5403654584661126
```

Comment: It won't resolve to a different copy if module path is the same (and it is the same). For loose version restriction (like in my case) only one copy of third-party will be installed, `node_modules/third-party` with npm2, `node_modules/third-party@1.0.0` with npm3. There won't be `node_modules/a/node_modules/third-party`.