# Variable scope (module.exports + socket.io setup)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am setting up foundations for a websocket app using `node.js`, `express` and `socket.io`. I decided it would be elegant to place the code that sets up `socket.io` in a separate module, so my `server.js` file could be smaller, calling `require` for `socket.io` setup duties.

```
// server.js

// set up ======================================================================
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').Server(app);
var io      = require('socket.io')(server);
var port    = process.env.PORT || 80;

// routes ======================================================================
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// socket.io controller ========================================================
require('./app/ws-controller.js')(io);

// launch ======================================================================
server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + port + '!');
});
```

In my `ws-controller.js` file I placed some code to begin experimenting with `socket.io`.

```
// app/ws-controller.js
module.exports = function(io) {
    var numClients = 0;
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        numClients++;
        console.log(numClients);
    });
}
```

The client script embedded in `index.html` is minimal.

```
// client side script
var port = 80;
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:' + port);
```

Now to the point. Upon opening new browser tabs pointing to `localhost`, the server logs to the console increasing number `numClients`. How is that actually working? I was sure that `numClients` would be out of scope and expected to see an exception on the console. When the callback function bound to `on connection` events fires it shouldn't see the `numClients` variable since it is not global nor private to `io` object, right? What is actualy happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read more about closures in javascript. In this specific example, when you boot the application the `numClients = 0;` is initialized and remains in memory in the execution context of the anonymous `function(io)`. Then, every time that there is a new connection, the `io.on('connection')` event is triggered, the callback is executed, the `numClients` is still in the execution context and that's why you will see this var to be incremented.

Comment: So when the `io.on('connection')` event is triggered, the callback is executed still in the context of `function(io)`? I thought it would be a fresh one, since the setup function was created, executed and forgotten (at least that's what I reasoned).

Comment: @Apo this is not the case for node modules. When you require a module, node will cache the module so that if another file will require the module it will return the same instance. This will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210542/node-js-require-cache-possible-to-invalidate

Comment: read more on closures it will help you clear the doubt. It's one the feature which makes JavaScript so powerful and expressive.

Comment: @Svabael - got it. The link you provided was helpful indeed, especially one of the less popular answers by Erik Reppen who described what would be the behavior in closure-less environment.