# Node.js load json without require

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON object that I'm loading every 2 seconds.

If I use:

```
colorObj = require('file.json');
```

It causes `file.json` to be cached and the values will never update.

Comment: In what environment? Can't you just read the file?

Comment: @DaveNewton sorry I should have mentioned I'm using node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a custom require function, found in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16060619/773263).

```
function requireUncached(module){
    delete require.cache[require.resolve(module)]
    return require(module)
}
```