# express config from json stranges

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Good time to all. Recently started learn javascript and experiment with node server coding and now really can't understand what is happening..

I have classic app.js

```
...
var view = require('./routes/view');
...
app.use('/mix', view);
...
```

And this is my view.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var moment = require("moment");

var DB = require('../modules/mysql')

/*  */
router.get('/:mixId', (req, res, next) => {

  /** set defaults */
  let config = require('../cfg/hbs.json'); // config load (see example below)
  var page = "pages/viewFail",
    alert = {};

  /** select info about mix */
  DB.query('SELECT startTS, targetAdr, received FROM mixes m WHERE name=?', [req.params.mixId], (err, results) => {

    /** if not exist */
    if (results.length === 0) {
      alert = { // danger alert
        "color": "danger",
        "text": "this mix does not exist"
      }
    }
    /** exist */
    else {

      var mix = {
        "adr": results[0].targetAdr,
        "received": results[0].received,
        /** calculate endin in minudes */
        "endin": parseInt(120 - moment.duration(moment().diff(moment(results[0].startTS))).asMinutes()),
      }

      /** check end time and ballance. if no transactions and time ends - exit */
      if (mix.endin <= 0 && mix.received <= 0) {
        alert = {
          "color": "danger",
          "text": "this mix does not exist"
        }
      } else {

        if (mix.received == 0) {
          page = 'pages/viewStart'
        } else {
          config.meta.js.push("/js/viewEnd.js"); /** add common page js {} */
          page = 'pages/viewEnd'

          console.log(config.meta)
          console.log("\n------------\n")

        }
      }
    }


    /** send response */
    res.render(page, {
      layout: 'layout',
      meta: config.meta,
      alert: alert,
      mix: mix,
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my config file:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "title": "test partials",
    "css": [
      "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "/css/c.css"
    ],
    "js": [
      "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js",
      "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js",
      "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ],
    "tmp": [
      "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    ]

  }
}
```

And the problem is: when I restart page meta.js add time after time and result is:

```
{ title: 'test partials',
  css: 
   [ 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css',
     '/css/c.css' ],
  js: 
   [ 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js',
     'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js',
     'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js',
     '/js/viewEnd.js',  // ??????
     '/js/viewEnd.js',  // ??????
     '/js/viewEnd.js' ],// ??????
  tmp: [ 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js' ] }
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Forgot to said that im using handlebars and in my template code is:   {{#each meta.js}}
 <script src="{{.}}"></script>
{{/each}}    But don't think this is mattered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
let config1 = require('../cfg/hbs.json');
let config2 = require('../cfg/hbs.json');

console.log(config1 === config2);
```

This will log the value `true`, meaning that `config1` and `config2` refer to the exact same object.

The reason for this is that `require` performs caching. It will only read the file the first time. Subsequent calls to `require` the same file will just return the cached object.

This is what's happening in your code. Each time the route is called it's pulling in the same `config` object and then pushing an extra entry into the same array.

There are several ways to resolve this. One simple solution is to take a deep copy of the object by JSON encoding it:

```
let config = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(require('../cfg/hbs.json')));
```

Comment: Thansk a lot. Found another solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210542/node-js-require-cache-possible-to-invalidate, but your is prettier.