# Change dotenv variables during unit tests

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js, supertest

I have a `.env` file with `MYVAR=1` variable in it.

server.js

```
//...   
var app = express();  
//... 
if(app.get("env")==="development"){
  require('dotenv').config();
}
console.log("server------",process.env. MYVAR) //outputs 1
if(process.env.MYVAR==1){
   //do this  
}
if(process.env.MYVAR==2){
   //do this 
}
module.exports = app;
```

test.server.js

```
app = require('../server'),
supertest = require('supertest');
require('dotenv').config();

describe('Server TESTS', function () {
    let request = null
    let server = null

    before(function (done) {
        process.env.MYVAR = 2;
        server = app.listen()
        request = supertest.agent(server)
        done()
    });

    after(function (done) {
        console.log("client------",process.env. MYVAR) //outputs 2
        server.close(done)
    });

})
```

Problem:
After I run `mocha test`, my `MYVAR` does not reflect `server.js` file and it remains as `1`. Even if I comment out `require('dotenv').config();` in `server.js`

How do I overcome this, maybe my supertest agent structure is not correct. Please advice.

**UPDATE:**

Instead of `server = app.listen()`, `server = require('../server').listen()`
 worked as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Just try to call `process.env.MYVAR = 2;` before `app = require('../server')`:

```
require('dotenv').config();
process.env.MYVAR = 2;
var app = require('../server');
var supertest = require('supertest');
```

There is a better way to handle test environment variables you can create a `test/mocha.env.js` file and then add `--require test/mocha.env.js` to `mocha.opts`, but still it depends on what you need.

Comment: I need to change MYVAR dynamically on each test case

Comment: Are you sure that you need environment variables for this? But anyway the main problem is that your script is running before you initialize MYVAR. So, you can wrap the code that uses those variables in a function and call it after `process.env.MYVAR = 2;`

Comment: Instead of `server = app.listen()`, `server = require('../server').listen()`     
 worked as expected.

Comment: If it comes to extensively testing this neat litte npm package mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31505483/810568) is very useful too.

Answer (score 2):

I've found unit testing code that uses `process.env` is much easier if you move it to a separate module and stub that out during test:

```
// config/env.js
export default process.env;

// server.js
import env from 'config/env';

if (env.MYVAR === 2) {
  ...
}

// server.test.js
// stub config/env.js with library of your choice
```