# require.cache equivalent in ES modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, ecmascript-6, module

[ES Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_no_require_cache) docs states:

> require.cache is not used by import. It has a separate cache.

So where's this *separate cache*? Is it accessible after all?

I'm looking for invalidating module caching as it can be done in *CommonJS modules* ([node.js require() cache - possible to invalidate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210542/node-js-require-cache-possible-to-invalidate))

Comment: I have this exact same question

Comment: i have the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74216420/access-the-imported-packages-cache-like-require-cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw your thread on the nodeJS github and your answer is there: the cache is designed to be immutable. There's also a good suggestion to use Workers, with each instance having its own fresh imports. Short of that, if you need this behaviour (which doesn't exist for a reason), is there perhaps a better way to design your application to not need it?

EDIT: The issue on GH: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1399