# Require multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js

File `my_script.js`:

```
(function() {
    console.log("IMPORTED");
})();
```

Calling this file (`run_me.js`) should cause `IMPORTED` to print twice:

```
require("./my_script");
require("./my_script");
```

However it only prints once.

How can I change `run_me.js` so that `IMPORTED` is printed to the console twice.

**Assume for this question, no changes can be made to `my_script.js`**

Comment: why do you want to import twice? you can `my_script` to print twice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js require() cache - possible to invalidate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210542/node-js-require-cache-possible-to-invalidate)

Comment: Is this node, webpack, other?

Comment: @andrewgi I don't want to edit `my_script`. Humour me for this one

Comment: @AndyRay Nodejs, check the question tags

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`require()` caches its results.  So, the first time a module is required, then its initialization code runs.  After that, the cache just returns the value of module.exports without running the initialization code again.  This is a very desirable feature of node.js modules.

If you want code to be run each time, then you should export a function that you can call after you require it like this:

Your module:

```
module.exports = function() {
    console.log("IMPORTED");
}
```

Requiring it and running the code each time

```
require("./my_script")();
require("./my_script")();
```

Also, please note that there is no reason to use an IIFE in a module.  The node.js module is automatically wrapped in a private function already so you don't need to do it again.

---

As you now say in a comment (but your question does not directly say), if you don't want to edit my_script at all (which is simply the wrong way to solve this issue), then you have to delete the module from the node.js cache before requiring it again which can be done like this:

```
delete require.cache[require.resolve('./my_script')];
```

I would not recommend this as a solution.  It's not the proper way to code in node.js.  It's a hack work-around.  And, it is not compatible with ESM modules.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck with the bad approach. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: why is the bad approach so bad?

Comment: @JoshMcGee - If you want a module to be mutable (run itself over and over again), then just design a function that you export from the function and call that as many times as you want.  To delete it from the cache just so you can run it again is a hack.  That's now how modules are designed to work and there's no guarantee that the newer ESM modules can ever work that way.  Besides if you want the module to have a specific feature, then build that feature into the module itself rather than trying to hack around to make it run its initialization code again.

Answer (score 8):

If you use jest and want code to be run each time for testing, you can use [jest.isolateModules](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestisolatemodulesfn):

```
jest.isolateModules(() => {
    require("./my_script");
});

jest.isolateModules(() => {
    require("./my_script");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible without modifying the `myscript.js` file. Especially since as you show it, it doesn't export anything.

It will execute the first time you require it (which is why you see "Imported" once), but then nothing will happen on future calls to require because the "cached" value (ie. `module.exports`) which is returned is empty.

See below for an example of what I think you want (except that myscript.js has been modified). The biggest difference is that in your original `myscript.js` file the function was actually executed, while in the example below it is just defined, and then actually executed in the `require` call in the `run_me.js` file.

File `myscript.js`:

```
module.exports = () => console.log("Imported");
```

File `run_me.js`:

```
require('myscript.js')(); // note the () at the end which actually calls the function
require('myscript.js')(); // note the () at the end which actually calls the function
```

Comment: This solution worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210542/node-js-require-cache-possible-to-invalidate

Answer (score -1):

You can use this package, it is an npm module that will clear the cache and load a module from source fresh each time.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-uncached

```
const requireUncached = require('require-uncached');

require('./foo')();
//=> 1

require('./foo')();
//=> 2

requireUncached('./foo')();
//=> 1

requireUncached('./foo')();
//=> 1
```