# Node hot reload

Tags: node.js, caching, require

i wanted to implement an hot-reload feature in my app.

Basically when i change a file that returns a value i want it to be working on my **running** application.

This involves some require.cache knowledge that maybe i got wrong,
i've found a small repo that i thought it could help me with no chance.

The repo is [clear-module](https://github.com/sindresorhus/clear-module/issues/5) and i prepared a small example on top of it

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:giggioz/test-clear-module.git
```

install the modules with

```
npm i
```

and then run it with

```
node index.js
```

This code prints every 500ms a value.
This value comes from a delegate.

**My Issue**

If i change the value returned by get-points.js **while the code is running**  it does not do anything... i would expect a change, right?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use the node.js built in debugger

Comment: @user9335240 can you give me some link to resources pls?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/debugger.html, just write `node inspect index.js` and you are in the debug mode

Comment: I've found [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14801711/3438453).