# nodejs re-import file when it changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, chokidar

My main code is under chokidar watched folder, when a file changes it emit an event

The main script is this

```
const fileName = "test.ts";
import(fileName).then((t: any) => {
  t.default();
});
```

and this is the file test.ts

```
export default () => {
  console.log("aaa");
};
```

I need to reimport file when I change test.ts, for example, I need this

> START script
>
> OUTPUT "aaa"
>
> CHANGE test.ts from "console.log("aaa")" to "console.log("bbb")"
>
> OUTPUT "bbb"

Comment: For me it was a better solution handling the invalidation myself as not only the imported file directly needed to me invalidated but also a subsequent import. So I found this more helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210542/node-js-require-cache-possible-to-invalidate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use **decache**, full code is this (with **chokidar** folder watcher)

```
const folder = chokidar.watch("./myFolder", {
    ignored: /(^|[\/\\])\../,
    persistent: true,
});
folder
.on("add", (fileName: string) => {
    const mod = require(fileName)
    mod.default();
.on("change", (fileName: string) => {
    decache(fileName);
    const mod = require(fileName)
    mod.default();
})
```