# How to invalidate cached require.resolve() results

Tags: node.js

**Note: this is NOT the same question as [node.js require() cache - possible to invalidate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210542/node-js-require-cache-possible-to-invalidate/16060619)**.

I'm writing a script which modifies the `main` entry point in the `package.json` of a Node.js package and I am having difficulty testing its behaviour.

Here's the example package whose `main` entry point I'm trying to modify. It consists of three files.

`./node_modules/example/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "a.js"
}
```

`./node_modules/example/a.js`:

```js
module.exports = { letter: 'A' }
```

`./node_modules/example/b.js`:

```js
module.exports = { letter: 'B' }
```

As you can see, this package loads `a.js` right now, but my script will change it to load `b.js` instead.

Here's my script:

```js
const fs = require('fs')

// Here is what we get at first
const first = require('example')
console.log(first) // { letter: 'A' }

// Now rewrite the package.json
const p = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./node_modules/example/package.json', 'utf8'))
console.log(p.main) // 'a.js'
p.main = 'b.js'
fs.writeFileSync('./node_modules/example/package.json', JSON.stringify(p, null, 2))

// Require the module a second time
// We get the same object a second time, because of well-documented caching behaviour
// <https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching>
const second = require('example')
console.log(second === first) // true
console.log(second) // { letter: 'A' }

// Clear the cache, as documented
// <https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_cache>
// <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210542/node-js-require-cache-possible-to-invalidate/16060619>
delete require.cache[require.resolve('example')]

// Require the module a third time
// We get a new object... but it's still the old entry point
const third = require('example')
console.log(third === first) // false - a new object
console.log(third) // { letter: 'A' } - STILL THE SAME? should be 'B'
```

As you can see, after rewriting and saving the new `package.json`, **and clearing the `require` cache**, Node.js is *still* loading the old module!

Digging a little deeper, I've discovered that the value returned from `require.resolve('example')` is still `./node_modules/example/a.js`, even though it should be `./node_modules/example/b.js` now. In other words, it looks as if there is some kind of secondary cache for the results of `require.resolve`.

My question is this: is there any way for me to access and modify this secondary cache?

Comment: did you explore using node's `vm` module to provide different execution environments using different implementations of `require`? I'm not in front of a PC right now so can't test it myself; just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently it is impossible to do this. The contents of each `package.json` loaded by Node.js is cached separately in a variable [`packageJsonCache`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/dcba12895ad58275ba5b027c2c5110461dfebf66/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L239), which is not externally reachable without the addition of a new feature to Node.js' [Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) API.