# Node.js Function not updating value after 1st invoke

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've recently taken interest in the Discord.js framework, and was designing a bot for a server. Apologies in advance for the messiness of the code.

The issue I'm facing is that after I first run the command, the the function is invoked, the value of `ticketValue` does not update to the update value in my JSON file.

```
const fs = require("fs");


module.exports = {
    commands: ["ticket"],
    minArgs: 1,
    expectedArgs: "<message>",

    callback: (message, arguments, text) => {

      // Console Log to notify the function has been invoked.
      console.log("FUNCTION RUN")


      let jsondata = require("../ticketNum.json")
      let ticketValue = jsondata.reportNews.toString()

      // Turning the number into a 4 digit number.
        for(let i = ticketValue.length; i<4;i++) {
            ticketValue = `0${ticketValue}`
        }
        console.log(`#1 ${ticketValue}`)

        // Creating the Discord Chanel
        message.guild.channels.create(`report-incident-${ticketValue}`, {
            type: 'text',
            permissionOverwrites: [
               {
                 id: message.author.id,
                 deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
              },
            ],
          })

          // Adding one to the ticket value and storing it in a JSON file.
          ticketValue = Number(ticketValue)+1
           console.log(`TICKET VALUE = ${ticketValue}`)
          fs.writeFile("./ticketNum.json",JSON.stringify({"reportNews": Number(ticketValue)}), err => {
             console.log(`Done writing, value = ${ticketValue}`)
          })


            console.log(require("../ticketNum.json").reportNews.toString())
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is due to something called [require cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210542/node-js-require-cache-possible-to-invalidate). You can either invalidate the cache for your JSON file each time you write to it, or preferably use `fs.readFile` to get the up-to-date contents.

Also worth noting that you are requiring from `../ticketNum.json` but you are writing to `./ticketNum.json`. This could also be a cause.

You seem to be using JSON files as a database and while that is perfectly acceptable depending on your project's scale, I would recommend something a little more polished like [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb) which stills uses local JSON files to store your data but provides a nicer API to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You should only use `require` when the file is static while the app is running.

1. The caching `require` performs is really useful, especially when you are loading tons of modules with the same dependencies.
2. `require` also does some special stuff to look for modules locally, globally, etc.  So you might see unintended things happen if a file is missing locally and `require` goes hunting.

These two things mean it's not a good replacement for the `fs` tools node provides for file access and manipulation.

Given this, you should use `fs.readFileSync` or one of the other read functions.  You're already using `fs` to write, so that isn't a large lift in terms of changing the line or two where you have `require` in place or a read.