# How to clear module cache and import a module for hot reloading in TypeScript in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, import, module

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16060619/169992) before, many times, back before ES6 modules and `import` in the `require` days:

```
function requireUncached(module) {
    delete require.cache[require.resolve(module)];
    return require(module);
}
```

However, when I try a similar thing in Node.js v18.16.0 with this command:

```
npx ts-node test.ts
```

and this `test.ts`:

```
import fs from 'fs'

boot()

async function boot() {
  // simulate a dynamic path...:
  const path = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify('./foo.ts'))
  save(path, "const x = 20");
  let file = await load(path)
  console.log(String(file))
  save(path, 'const x = 100');
  file = await load(path);
  console.log(String(file));
}

async function load(path: string) {
  delete require.cache[require.resolve(path)]
  return (await import(path)) as unknown
}

function save(path: string, code: string) {
  fs.writeFileSync(path, code)
}
```

And assuming a file `./foo.ts` exists.

I get basically:

```
./node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-internal-errors.js:46
  const err = new Error(getErrRequireEsmMessage(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath))
              ^
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: ./test.ts
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of ./test.ts is an ES module file as it is a .ts file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .ts files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from ./package.json.

    at createErrRequireEsm (./node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-internal-errors.js:46:15)
```

How do you dynamically import a module in Node.js / ES6 *and* clear the cache, so you can import it fresh every call?

I have `"type": "module"` in my package.json so I can use ES6 features, but if there's another way I'm all ears. I have several modules built on each other all using this pattern.

If it's [not exposed](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2806), how else can I import a dynamic fresh module?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to accomplish that with the import syntax because the module cache was handled in CJS modules while in ESM modules it's handled by the Javascript engine itself. I believe the cleverest would actually be to just avoid caching and find other ways to reach the same goal.