# Prevent RequireJS from Caching Required Scripts on Nodejs

Tags: node.js, caching, requirejs

I am using something like [airbnb's rendr](https://github.com/airbnb/rendr), i.e. [my own implementation of sharing backbone code between client and server](http://www.slideshare.net/stephanfortelny/backbone-pipedream-final), to build full HTML on the server using the same Backbone models, views, collections and templates I am using on the client. My files/modules are defined as requirejs modules, that way I can share them easily on the client.
In development mode, I want requirejs to refetch/reload any modules from disc when I refresh my browser (without restarting the server), so I get my server rendering uses the newest templates and javascript to finally serve me the newest HTML.

when using requirejs on the server with nodejs, [the trick of appending *bust* parameters to the urlArgs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315088/prevent-requirejs-from-caching-required-scripts) like the following doesn't work, i.e. the server doesn't reload/refetch any modules from disc

```
urlArgs: "bust=v2"
```

I wonder, if reloading/refetching requirejs modules from disc-space without restarting the server is possible in node? specifically, that would be very useful for [the require-text plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text) for template. additionally, it would be nice to apply reloading only to a restricted set of modules.

Comment: You again! :P How exactly does it _not work_? Also, I find `urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()` is better while you're developing. Also also, why aren't you using node's `require` system?

Comment: hi c24w :-) I updated my answer. I hope it's clearer now

Answer (score 2):

I've never had to do this, but a quick search shows [a few options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1972242/706561), including automating the server restart:

- [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon)
- [node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor)

You may also be able to do something similarly creative to this:

- `delete require.cache['/home/shimin/test2.js']`

You could almost definitely clear the version RequireJS has in cache, forcing it to reload it, although I suspect the node would just serve up the old file again.

Finally, maybe take a look at *hot-reloading*, which seems to work around the caching without needing to restart the server ([example](https://github.com/shimondoodkin/node-hot-reload)).

Comment: Thanks for hint `delete require.cache[]` I needed to have always fresh content from some postcss required file during webpack watch or webpack dev server.

Answer (score 1):

Like the OP, I was looking for a way to make development in node with RequireJS easier and faster. In my case, I am using RequireJS with a grunt `watch` task in node, and wanted to be able to force RequireJS to always get the latest version of a module from the file system. And happily, I found a very [simple solution](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/requirejs/ir3e5SF3ea0/hFvUMfJ571wJ)!

I had to slightly modify Henning Kvinnesland’s suggestion by adding the timeout, but now it is working like a charm:

```js
var requirejs = require('requirejs');
// Set up requirejs.config here...
// Disable caching of modules
requirejs.onResourceLoad = function(context, map) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        requirejs.undef(map.name);
    }, 1);
};
```