# Can I make nodejs work after each modification without restarting server

Tags: node.js

I'm new to Node.js. For each modification in code, I have to restart server to make it work. I wonder if there are any ways to make it work without restarting server. Thanks.

Comment: This question is a possible duplicate of: [Auto-reload of files in Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972242/auto-reload-of-files-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this npm plugin: https://npmjs.org/package/devreload

There is also a very cool NodeJS based framework called Meteor which does all of this automatically. It is very easy to learn, and does realtime code & content updates. I suggest looking into that as well.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems it's simple and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have not come across any which deploys server side scripts without restarting the server. There are node packages like [Forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever/), [Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) which listens to changes and deploys automatically.

Comment: Seems they are helpful tools, I will try these out. Million thanks.

Comment: Yeah. I have used them in about ten projects and they are good.

Comment: yeah, without concerning the deployment, just focus on your work ^_^