# Node 'resolve' with file watching and reloading

Tags: node.js

Let's assume the module I am requiring has no dependencies. For example, a json file, or a webpack compiled file.

Is there a built in method (or an npm package) that allows you to resolve live instances of files in node?

For example:

**foo.js**

```
module.exports = function() {
  return 'test!';
}
```

**implementation.js**

```
var liveFoo = require("live-monitor")("foo");
console.log(liveFoo.instance()); // this will auto update when saving foo.js.
```

I'd imagine this hypothetical node module `live-monitor` would internally use `fs.watch` to update the `instance` export as the file `foo.js` is changed.

So, anything built in to node? Any package out there that does this already?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/piping

Comment: Please comment if you vote to close.

Comment: Off-topic. You are asking to find or recommend off site library. And duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972242/auto-reload-of-files-in-node-js