# Node compile on file change

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm doing small programming challenges locally.

In one tab I draft a solution, let's call it `challenge.js` and in another tab I run the command `node challenge.js` whenever I make a change.

Is there a way for node to compile automatically whenever a change has been made to `challenge.js`?

Comment: this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972242/auto-reload-of-files-in-node-js

Comment: nodemon did the job, thanks

Answer (score 9):

The first comment answered the question.

I installed nodemon:

```
$ npm install nodemon -g
$ nodemon app.js
```

and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is for development environment?
If yes, you can use a build tool like webpack, gulp, etc.

[Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) provides a tool [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html), that recompile your bundle at every change.

I hope to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use nodemon. https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon I work in server development and it refershes the server every time I save a file. If its a case you want something live to restart every time it crashes or if theres any change use pm2
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2