# next js auto refresh

Tags: next.js, hmr

I have a problem which is that when I create a next js app the auto refresh does not work for me, when I make a change on the code I always have to shut down the app then run it again to see the changes. Any solutions please ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these links answer your problems: https://medium.com/@devdo/how-to-enable-fast-refresh-in-next-js-6b6d55f9d13f, https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/34689, https://nextjs.org/docs/architecture/fast-refresh, [Next.js : Refresh page after modifying a file, without rerunning 'npm run'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720692/next-js-refresh-page-after-modifying-a-file-without-rerunning-npm-run).

Let me know if these helped you.