# Make webpack-dev-server to do hot reloading AND eliminate EMPTY response error in React

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have been trying to make `React` app development easier by using reloading of the app when I modify the files and I tried `webpack-dev-server` for that (Please, see my previous thread: [Can't set up webpack-dev-server to start React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55345229/cant-set-up-webpack-dev-server-to-start-react-app)). I made hot reloading working but got an issue: timeouts started to occur on my requests and I see the empty response errors in console. There are threads that discuss the issue, e.g.: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/183
but so far I could not make it working. Setting `--host 0.0.0.0` is not working, setting `--port 3000` eliminates empty response error but hot reloading is gone... Below is my `webpack` relevant config:

```
  devServer: {
    index: '',
    open: true,
    proxy: {
      context: () => true, // endpoints which you want to proxy
      target: 'http://localhost:3000' // your main server address
    }
  },
  entry: {
    app: ['babel-polyfill', './views/index.js']
    //vendor: ["react","react-dom"]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public')
  },
  devtool: "#eval-source-map",
...
```

I am starting the app by running `npm run dev`, here is a part of the `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "client": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --devtool inline-source-map --port 3000 --content-base public --hot",
    "server": "node ./bin/www",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
  },
```

So, above if we remove `--port 3000` hot reloading on the front end part starts working, but then the timeout is happening. Also, upon modification of the server side code the app is not reloaded unfortunately and I am not sure how to add this feature too. I am using `react-hot-loader`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ControlledTabs from './ControlledTabs'
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root'

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <ControlledTabs/>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = hot(App);
```

I think it should be related to the `devServer` configs most probably and how the `webpack-dev-server` is started. I just want to find a `WORKING` way of doing hot reloading instead of falling back into `build` - `run` cycle that is annoying and inefficient.

Also, it is really hard to say, what is going wrong, whether `--port 3000` is really the issue. I noticed that the `webpack-dev-server` is somehow working in a very unpredictable way on my project meaning that after doing changes and launching the app I see one result, but then I restart `webpack-dev-server` and see a different result as if `webpack-dev-server` is doing something behind the scenes what it wants to and whenever it wants to without notifying me about that.

> Update

I changed `webpack.config.js` to:

```
watch: true,
  devServer: {
    index: '',
    open: true,
    proxy: {
      context: () => true, // endpoints which you want to proxy
      target: 'http://localhost:3000' // your main server address
    }
  },
  entry: {
    app: ['babel-polyfill', './views/index.js']
    //vendor: ["react","react-dom"]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public')
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  ],
```

And removed `react-hot-loader` from the `React` entry point:

```
import React from 'react';
import ControlledTabs from './ControlledTabs'

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <ControlledTabs/>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = App;
```

Because otherwise it was giving me a syntax error in console, `webpack` could not start. After doing that if I modify any react file, whole webpage is reloaded it seems and the `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` remains...

Comment: In your config you have `proxy.target: 'http://localhost:3000'`, so that means your main Node server is running on this port, right? But then you specify `--port 3000` for webpack-dev-server and I wonder how it started at all if your server occupies that port already?

Comment: So my guess is that you didn't have any server on port 3000 and dev-server proxied your client's requests to emptyness, therefore you got timeouts. And once you started dev-server on port 3000 those requests started to be sent to dev-server and it returned something (I wonder what :)). And I guess that somehow broke hot-reloading... not sure how though... `proxy.target` should define the address of your node server.
Can you please show some screenshots of failed requests?
'webpack-dev-server is somehow working in a very unpredictable way on my project ' - can you provide some more details?

Comment: My server is definitely running on port `3000`, that is for sure. The request is successful and the server starts executing the request, but the browser does not wait for it and times out on its own. It is not happening without the `webpack-dev-server` set up, so it is the reason somehow here.

Comment: Do your requests take long to finish? If so then try increasing timeout options for proxy: https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#http-proxy-options

Answer (score 1):

Add a watch to your webpack config.

```
watch: true
```

Also, you need to enable module replacement loading within the webpack dev server.

In short, if you see how this config is setup, this is a working example of hot reloading for a very basic react app.  It uses ExpressJS as well.

https://github.com/chawk/bare_bones_react/blob/master/webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const express = require('express');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        compress: true,
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        open: 'Chrome',
        before(app) {
            app.use('/static', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')))
        }
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        filename: './js/[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './server/index.html'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [
            '.js'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You see, I managed to make hot reloading  working fine but long running process on the server gives timeouts which should not happen. I think it is somehow related to `devServer` configs and how the `webpack-dev-server` is started because when I add `--port 3000` hot reloading is gone but timeouts are gone too. If I remove `--port 3000` timeouts issue comes.

Comment: Interesting, I personally haven't noticed that behavior with webpack dev server on windows.   I wish I could help further